# regression separately for specific variable

Tags: linear-regression

I am trying to run a lm/glm between two variables "area" and "intensity".

[image]

I ran a linear model regression between the variables with all rows combined and got summary results as below. I want to run the lm for the two variables individually for each city (A/B/C/D/E). How can I modify/loop the script such that I do not have to run the script 5 times, and the r-squared value and model results are added in the dataframe?

R1 <- lm(formula = area ~ intensity,
data = df1)
Call:
lm(formula = area ~ intensity, data = df1)

Residuals:
Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max
-2716.1 -1540.5  -684.3  1588.8  2686.8

### Coefficients:
Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  1646.30     569.73   2.890  0.00976 **
intensity    -333.10      42.73  -7.795 3.54e-07 ***

Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1790 on 18 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7715,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.7588
F-statistic: 60.77 on 1 and 18 DF,  p-value: 3.537e-07

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sharing a way to store a list of outputs and also a way to put results in primary dataframe:

```
results <- list()
cities <- unique(df1$city)
for (i in 1:length(cities)){
R1 <- lm(area ~ intensity, data=df1[df1$city==cities[i],])
results[[cities[i]]] <- summary(R1) # if you want to store everything
temp_df <- data.frame(prediceted=fitted(R1))
temp_df$city <- cities[i] 
temp_df$r_square <- summary(R1)$r.squared
if(i==1) result_df <- temp_df else result_df <- rbind(result_df, 
temp_df)
}

df1 <- merge(df1, result_df, by='city')
```